# Calculus and physical chemistry

Tags: physical-chemistry

Is calculus and differential equations really that useful in physical chemistry? How does knowing that helps me in physical chemistry? And how much of calculus must I know in order to do physical chemistry topics such as thermodynamics? Because I am currently a chem major and am wondering what maths courses would be relevant. I currently completed single variable calculus and intend to go on to multivariate calculus as well as differential equations. I wonder how useful that'd be.

Comment: University library, physical chemistry texts, look; Atkins, etc. While you are there, you must pass theoretical chemistry, too - all those bras and kets, psi. If you do not love what you are doing beyond all rational justification, go into management. 'Tis better to give than to receive, especially when whips are involved.

Comment: Indeed, my university requires that Chemical Engineers take math all the way up to partial differential equations.

Answer (score 5):

Calculus is the basis of physical chemistry. Have a look to [Maxwell relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations),[Clapeyron equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapeyron%27s_equation). How stated Uncle Al you should take a book of physical chemistry and look into, furthermore some books (see Atkins) have an appendix showing you the mathematical skills required to understand the content of the book. Here what you should know only for thermodynamics in my opinion:

- algebra
- logarithms
- vectors
- calculus
- **Partial derivative**
- differential equations

If you go deep into the atoms more mathematical skills are required.

Answer (score 1):

My university required calculus (2 courses) and differential equations (1 course) to complete the chemistry degree.